# Using if-else statement inside Groovy - spock test

Tags: java, testing, groovy, automated-tests, spock

Currently when I use if else in a Groovy - spock **when:**, only the if is executed and the else is not. Is there any other way of implementing if-else inside spock tests? I tried switch case and encountered the same.

```
if (value == 'x' || 'y' || 'z') {
    //execute below info
} else if (value == 'a') {
    //execute below info
}
```

Comment: why do you have this: ``` || 'y' || 'y' ```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the groovy truth 'y' is treated as boolean **true**, that's why **else** is not executed.

Probably you tried to evaluate this:

```
if (value == 'x' || value == 'y' || value == 'y') {
    //execute below info
} else if (value == 'z'){
    //execute below info
}
```

But also you can try to modify the if-expression to:

```
if (value in ['x', 'y', 'y']) {...}
```

Comment: I used the second one, it works. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have to make this a comment or an answer.

Your code under the else block is not executing because `value == 'x' || 'y' || 'y'` is always true because the character literal `'y'` is always evaluated to true.

> Non-empty Strings, GStrings and CharSequences are coerced to true.

Try this: `if (value == 'x' || value == 'y' )`

Comment: Got it. Thanks Degen!